# MAUI sfScheduler - passing in API data into Scheduler

Tags: c#, maui, syncfusion

I have a .Net MAUI app (target platform And, iOS & Win) im trying to use the SyncFusion Scheduler for the first time..

I have everything working if I hard code data to return from the ViewModel and into the scheduler..
but im struggling to figure out how to convert the data retruned from the API into the SchedulerAppointments.

XAML:

```
<scheduler:SfScheduler x:Name="calendar" View="Month" FirstDayOfWeek="Monday" AllowedViews="Week ,Month"   
                             TodayHighlightBrush="Gray" AppointmentsSource=" {Binding SchedulerEvents}" Tapped="calendar_Tapped" >

            <scheduler:SfScheduler.MonthView>
                <scheduler:SchedulerMonthView AppointmentDisplayMode="Indicator"  />
            </scheduler:SfScheduler.MonthView>

            <scheduler:SfScheduler.BindingContext >
                <local:SchedulerControlViewModel>
                    
                </local:SchedulerControlViewModel>
            </scheduler:SfScheduler.BindingContext>
</scheduler:SfScheduler>
```

View Model:

```
using Syncfusion.Maui.Scheduler;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

namespace MyGolfSociety.ViewModels
{
    public class SchedulerControlViewModel
    {
        public ObservableCollection<SchedulerAppointment> SchedulerEvents { get; set; }
        public SchedulerControlViewModel()
        {

            this.SchedulerEvents = new ObservableCollection<SchedulerAppointment>
            {
                new SchedulerAppointment
                {
```

//THE HARDED CODED DATA I NEED TO REPLACE WITH THE ObservableCollection

```
                    StartTime = new DateTime(2023, 8, 5,00,01,01),
                    EndTime = new DateTime(2023, 8, 5,23,01,01),
                    Subject = "TEST Appointment",
                    IsAllDay = true

                }
            };

        }
    }
}
```

Events Model:

```
namespace MyGolfSociety.Models
{
    public class Events
    {
        public int EventId { get; set; }

        public string? EventName { get; set; }

        public DateTime EventDateStart { get; set; }

        public DateTime? EventDateEnd { get; set; }

        public int? CourseId { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I have returned an ObservableCollection of type Events (which is my model) but im not sure how to convert or pass in the content of the Observable collection into the Schedule Appointment without just lopping the the collection.. surly there has to be a better more efficient way..?

Comment: the [docs](https://help.syncfusion.com/maui/scheduler/getting-started#creating-the-custom-eventsappointments-with-data-mapping) explicitly cover how to do this

Comment: So looks like the only way to do it is to loop through the collection.. I assumed that would be inefficient and there was a better way - but thanks once again for the insight..

All great learning for me..

Comment: I don't think that's true.  Did you read the section "Mapping the data object to scheduler appointment"?

Comment: Sorry Jason your right. I miss interpreted that (note to self - stop rushing, this is definitelya learnong process for me).. appologies and thankyou again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Jason suggested, you may need to map those properties of the Model:`Events` class by using the [AppointmentMapping](https://help.syncfusion.com/cr/maui/Syncfusion.Maui.Scheduler.SchedulerAppointmentMapping.html) property like below:

```
<scheduler:SfScheduler  x:Name="calendar" 
                        View="Month" 
                        FirstDayOfWeek="Monday" 
                        AllowedViews="Week ,Month"   
                        TodayHighlightBrush="Gray" 
                        AppointmentsSource=" {Binding SchedulerEvents}" 
                        Tapped="calendar_Tapped" >
    <scheduler:SfScheduler.AppointmentMapping>
        <scheduler:SchedulerAppointmentMapping
                Subject="TEST Appointment"
                StartTime="EventDateStart"
                EndTime="EventDateEnd"
                IsAllDay="IsAllDay"
                Id="EventId" />
    </scheduler:SfScheduler.AppointmentMapping>

     <scheduler:SfScheduler.MonthView>
           <scheduler:SchedulerMonthView AppointmentDisplayMode="Indicator"/>
     </scheduler:SfScheduler.MonthView>

      <scheduler:SfScheduler.BindingContext >
                <local:SchedulerControlViewModel>   
                </local:SchedulerControlViewModel>
      </scheduler:SfScheduler.BindingContext>
</scheduler:SfScheduler>
```